# Need help changing Ruby URL syntax to get rid of field type and use only field name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

So we all know that Ruby will let you access fields like this...

**localhost:3000/stuff/1**, **localhost:3000/otherthing/5**

I already figured out how to not use the numbered id as the identifying field in the url using the [Friendly_Id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem. What I am trying to find out if its possible is to JUST have the field name in the url. For example

Instead of **localhost:3000/pizza/1** I could have **localhost:3000/cheese**.

I want to try and do this because the site I am building with havea number of 'parent' objects that each have different iterations of children objects.

There will be 'school' objects that will have different 'professor' and 'department' and 'class' objects. I want to try and change the url to be something like

**localhost:3000/rutgers/classes/Chem101** instead of **localhost:3000/schools/1/classes/10**

So for each type of child object I could have:

- localhost:3000/rutgers/departments/chem
- localhost:3000/rutgers/classes/chem101
- localhost:3000/rutgers/professors/frizzle

I'm a Java dev and I've just started familiarizing myself with Ruby so I'm wondering if this is possible.

Comment: Look into firendly_id gem: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

Comment: I'm already looking into that for the change to localhost:3000/pizza/cheese, It can do localhost:3000/cheese too? If so, that'll be pretty nice.

Comment: Unfortunately not, those needs to be changed in your routes, but this gem will help you with it as well.

Answer (score 1):

To change `classes/10` to `classes/chem` you definitively want to use [friendly_id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id). As for changing `schools/1` to `rutgers` you will additionally need a small tweak in your routes:

```
resources :schools, path: nil do #=> this will remove `/schools` from the route
  resources :classes
  ...
end
```

This will cause your routes to look like this (example for classes#show):

```
/:school_id/classes/:id
```

were both `school_id` and `id` can be friendly_id.